# Does a poker party always end with one player winning all the chips?

Tags: rules

I've seen some guys playing Texas Hold 'em and each time it ends with one of them taking all the chips on the table. Does it always work that way, or are there some limits?

Comment: The question very broad and vague. I can't see how it will inspire a serious answer that would benefit other players, other than differentiating between Cash games and Tournaments. For that reason, I'm closing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cash games players may enter and exit the game at any time.

In the tournament the winner is a player who has taken all the chips from another players.